# Figure label in parentheses

Tags: formatting, numbering, captions, subfloats

I use the following code for displaying four figures.  When I compile, I get each figure with label as a, b, c and d. I want these labels to be displayed with parenthesis as (a), (b), (c) and (d). How can I do this?

```
\begin{figure*}[ht] 
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{figure_a} 
            \caption{}
        \label{fig7:a} 
        \vspace{4ex}
    \end{subfigure}%% 
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{figure_b} 
        \caption{} 
        \label{fig7:b} 
        \vspace{4ex}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{figure_c} 
        \caption{} 
        \label{fig7:c} 
    \end{subfigure}%%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{figure_d} 
        \caption{} 
        \label{fig7:d} 
    \end{subfigure} 
    \caption{My caption }
    \label{myfig}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: What package do you use that supplies the `subfigure` environment?

Answer (score 1):

This is the default style provided by the [`subcaption` package](//ctan.org/pkg/subcaption):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[ht] 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}%% 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
    \caption{} 
  \end{subfigure} 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-c} 
    \caption{} 
  \end{subfigure}%%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
    \caption{} 
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{My caption}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

The above style can be modified using the functionality of [`caption`](//ctan.org/pkg/caption) (since it's written by the same author).